# how can I construct the alamofire query based on array entries in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I have a class `SingleUser`:

```
class SingleUser: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var username: String
    var display_name: String
    var facebook_username: String
    var device_id: String
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and I have an array of those users:

```
let blockedUsers: [SingleUser] = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:
                    (defaults.object(forKey: "myUsers") as! Data)) as! [SingleUser]
```

I want to pass it with `Alamofire` to my webservice.

I have already some parameters defined:

```
var params = [
    "long": lon as AnyObject,
    "lat": lat as AnyObject,
    "startDate": DateCalc.convertValueToDate(defaults.float(forKey: "startDate")) as AnyObject,
    "endDate": DateCalc.convertValueToDate(defaults.float(forKey: "endDate")) as AnyObject
] as [String: AnyObject]
```

and now I want to append my users somehow, e.g. as:

```
"users" = { 
      { "username" = "xxxx",
        "display_name" = "xxxx",
        "facebook_username" = "xxxx",
        "device_id" = "xxxx"
       },
       { "username" = "yyyy",
        "display_name" = "yyyy",
        "facebook_username" = "yyyy",
        "device_id" = "yyyy"
       },
       .
       .
       .
       }
```

Can you tell me how could I iterate over that array and append it to my `params` array?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SingleUser: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var username: String
    var display_name: String
    var facebook_username: String
    var device_id: String

    var jsonFormat: [String: AnyObject] {
        return  ["username": username,
                 "display_name": display_name,
                 "facebook_username": facebook_username,
                 "device_id": device_id]
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var users = [[String: AnyObject]]()
blockedUsers.forEach { user in
    users.append(user.jsonFormat)
}
params["users"] = users
```

Comment: Thank you @Bart, it almost works... I did what you suggested and then I wrote `print(params)` and I see: `["users": <Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x174238340>( {` and the rest is fine... why do I have here this weird deferred ns array and how can I get rid off it?